# Multiple @font-face not working in IE9–11 or Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, fonts, font-face

I have a site in development that uses four external fonts. Trajan and Museo are working fine through Typekit, but my other two (Marketing Script and Socialico) are having trouble in IE9–11 and Firefox. I’ve tried a variety of path changes and hacks to get them to display, but they unwaveringly will not.

Test site at http://www.wwva.org.php53-14.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/students (you may need to full screen to see Socialico in the left bar).

I am currently including a secondary stylesheet using a CSS @import. I have tried including the @font-face declarations directly at the top of the style.css file as well, with same results. The @font-face declarations look like this (relative paths verified):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Socialico';
  src: url('socialico-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local("☺"),
       url('socialico-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('socialico-webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('socialico-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('socialico-webfont.svg#Socialico') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
     }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'marketingScript';
    src: url('marketingscript-webfont.eot');
    src: local("☺"),
         url('marketingscript-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('marketingscript-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('marketingscript-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('marketingscript-webfont.svg#marketingScript') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
```

I’ve already done some digging on StackOverflow, but it’s definitely possible I missed something. I have not done any permission/configuration changes on Firefox, because that would only solve the issue locally, and not for other viewers once the site goes live.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Socialico is rendering fine for me. (Fx 27.0.1/Win7.) Can't find anywhere on the page where you're using `marketingScript`; I assume the browser won't download the font if it's not used.

Comment: I did in fact use marketingScript on #flagText (the big word in the banner). Nice catch on the Socialico error on my part.

Also, see my answer to my own question. I made a simple syntax error in the actual call to marketingScript in my CSS (forgot a comma).

I appreciate your time in looking at this issue—sorry to waste your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goodness, I feel like a doof. I had scoured the @font-face code so many times that I became fixated on it, while apparently neglecting the actual call to apply the code. I left out a comma between the primary and secondary font-face values, producing inconsistent results due to broken syntax.

Let it be known—it’s always a good idea to proofread *all* of one’s code.

I apologize for wasting your time!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has a pref (security.csp.enable) 
 Go to your site's .htaccess and disable CSP

Since you tested this prior to this edit, you are pretty much left with two alternative solutions. I think the makers of that font may not have made it supportive of every browser. A lot of chatter in the blogs about the font not rendering in FF or IE Edge>

So here is what I'd do:

1. Replace it with an image.
2. Use Cufon.js

Either way, you will be safe because we are not exactly talking about a paragraph. It's just a word.

Hope that helped you some

Comment: I’m not quite sure what needs to be added to my .htaccess file to disable CSP, and even if I did I don’t have access to restart apache on the development server. I tried disabling it in about:config in Firefox, to no avail. Would this accomplish the same thing?

Comment: It's not the same. But there are two other ways you can still go through with this. I'll re-edit the answer.

Comment: I did try editing my .htaccess file as well, and it did _break_ the font support, site-wide. This, of course, was without a restart of apache, but wasn’t particularly promising.

Thanks for the above edit. Replacing with an image is not an option since the title is dynamically generated. Looks like I may need to go the Cufon.js route.

Your feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: Ah. Just found it. Simple syntax error elsewhere in my CSS. Posted as another answer for those curious. Sorry to have wasted your time—and thank you for your help in providing options!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Turns out I was missing a comma in the font-family declaration. E.g.

Broken:

```
body {
   font-family: 'Custom-Font' Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Works:

```
body {
   font-family: 'Custom-Font', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```